# How to use Electron's <webview> within Angular2 app?

Tags: webview, angular, attributes, electron, systemjs

I try to use [Electon's webview tag](https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/api/web-view-tag.md) inside my Angular2 app, but when I add the src attribute binded to an Angular2 variable, the following error occurs:

```
Can't bind to 'src' since it isn't a known native property
```

This is the index.html:

```
<head>
    <!-- cut out stylings, metatags, etc. -->
    <script src="../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js"></script>
    <script src="../node_modules/reflect-metadata/Reflect.js"></script>
    <script src="../node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>
    <script src="systemjs.config.js"></script>
    <script>
        const electron = require('electron');
        System.import('app').catch(function(err){ console.error(err); });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <MainComponent>Loading...</MainComponent>
</body>
```

This is the systemjs.config.js:

```
(function(global) {
// map tells the System loader where to look for things
var map = {
    'app':                        'angular',
    '@angular':                   '../node_modules/@angular',
    'angular2-in-memory-web-api': '../node_modules/angular2-in-memory-web-api',
    'rxjs':                       '../node_modules/rxjs'
};
// packages tells the System loader how to load when no filename and/or no extension
var packages = {
    'app':                        { main: 'main.js',  defaultExtension: 'js' },
    'rxjs':                       { defaultExtension: 'js' },
    'angular2-in-memory-web-api': { defaultExtension: 'js' }
};
var ngPackageNames = [
    'common',
    'compiler',
    'core',
    'http',
    'platform-browser',
    'platform-browser-dynamic',
    'router',
    'router-deprecated',
    'upgrade'
];
// Add package entries for angular packages
ngPackageNames.forEach(function(pkgName) {
    packages['@angular/'+pkgName] = { main: pkgName + '.umd.js', defaultExtension: 'js' };
});
var config = {
    map: map,
    packages: packages
};
System.config(config);
})(this);
```

This is the Angular2 component template I (want to) use webview in:

```
<div class="stage-component component">
    <webview *ngIf="iFrameUrl" src="{{iFrameUrl}}"></webview>
</div>
```

How can I introduce the webview element to Angular2?

Comment: Can you give a snippet of your html, version of electron and how you are running it?

Comment: I did update my question details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If this appears, use "attr" before.

```
<webview *ngIf="iFrameUrl" attr.src="{{iFrameUrl}}"></webview>
```

Comment: I was trying with src="{{iFrameurl}}" and it didn't work. thanks for this!

Answer (score 0):

That is strange. It sounds like you maybe have a version issue. You can try to use the [`loadUrl`](https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/api/web-view-tag.md#webviewloadurlurl-options) api instead and see if that helps.

```
<script>
  onload = () => {
    const webview = document.getElementById('foo');
    webview.loadUrl('http://example.com')
</script>
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure, this would work, but the webview has to be part of my Angular2 app :-(